# How to compare a Cell with DataGridViewCell CellType

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridView where the cells in a column can have differnt cell types.

For example the cell in row 1 has the cell type DataGridViewTextBoxCell.
And the cell in row 2 has the cell type DataGridViewImageCell.

I have created a method that does something if the mouse is over a cell of that column:

```
private void DataTableCellMouseEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if
    (
        e.RowIndex >= 0 // If the current row is not the header.
        && e.ColumnIndex == dataGridViewDMSSettings.Columns["Example"].Index // And if the current column is the example column.
    )
    {
        // Something happing here.
    }
}
```

Now I want to add a comparsion of the cell type to run the code only if the cell type is DataGridViewImageCell.

I have tried to add...

```
&& dataGridViewDMSSettings.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Example"].GetType() == DataGridViewImageCell
```

... but I'm getting the IntelliSense message "DataGridViewImageCell is a type and invalid in the current context."

Does someone have a solution for this?

Comment: `.GetType() == typeof(DataGridViewImageCell)`

Comment: Assuming it works like UITableViewCell, the base constructor requires a cellid.  I'm not sure how to get that inherrently, but you should be able to set it in your constructor and add your own function to get the cellid of the cell.

Comment: .GetType() == typeof(DataGridViewImageCell) worked, I didn't realized that i Need to get the type of the type :P

Comment: If you have an answer to your question and it hasn't been answered yet, you can add it as an answer. You shouldn't put the answer in your question or change the title to add "Solved".

Comment: Thanks for your addition JLRishe, I will do so in the future ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As indicated in the comments, you need to use the `typeof()` operator to use a type as a value. You can't use a type name as a value without that.

```
dataGridViewDMSSettings.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Example"].GetType() == 
    typeof(DataGridViewImageCell)
```

However, there is a much better way to check whether a value is of a particular type, and that is the `is` operator:

```
dataGridViewDMSSettings.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Example"].GetType() is 
    DataGridViewImageCell
```

An important difference here is that `is` respects inheritance relationships, while `==` plus `typeof()` requires exact type equivalence.

Comment: Also `dataGridViewDMSSettings.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Example"] is DataGridViewImageCell`